# C# Regex to match any character next to a specified substring but ignoring newline/tab character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2013

I want to match the character next to the word "Test" but if that next character is a newline `\n` character I need to get the character next to the newline charactger instead. In the following input string my `desired output` is character `C` and `w`. But I'm getting `\n` and `w` instead:

```
string str = "This abcTest\nCde and qrvTestwest is an input";
foreach (Match mt in Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=Test)(.)",RegexOptions.Singleline))
    Console.WriteLine(mt.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Is there an actual `newline` or just `\n` in the string ?

Comment: @noob In real file content there may be actual newlines after `Test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Test[\n]*(.)
```

It will skip over any number of newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for what you're asking is:

```
Test[\n](.)|Test(.)
```

You need to check both cases Test\n and Test(.).

Check a working regex of this: https://regex101.com/r/mI2tE5/1

For the comments this works better:

```
Test[\n]*(.)
```

Comment: Or, if you want to allow for multiple newlines, `Test[\n]*(.)` works and is simpler.

Comment: @Aschab In my C# code above `Test[\n](.)|Test(.)` pattern returns `C` and an empty string (the second match).

Comment: Just use `Test[\r\n]*(.)`

Comment: @MagikM18 Your solution works. Do you want to add it as a solution so I can mark it as an Answer.